# How to secure Android App that pulls data from OAuth protected resource

Tags: java, android, security, oauth, oauth-2.0

My company is building a RESTful API that will return moderately sensitive information (i.e. financial information, but not account numbers).  I have control over the RESTful API code/server and also am building the Android app.  I've setup the API to use OAuth 2 with authorization code grant flow (with client ID and secret), and I auto-approve users without them having to approve the client since we own both client and provider.  We use CAS for SSO and I am using this for the Authorization server as part of the OAuth 2 process when the user logs in to retrieve the token.

I am contemplating various ways to secure the data on the Android app.  I've concluded that storing the client id and secret on the device is definitely not going to happen, but am thinking that storing the auth token might work, since it is only risk to the individual user (and really only if they happen to have a rooted phone).

Here are two options I have thought of.  They both require me to have a sort of proxy server that is CAS protected, does the dance with the API server, and returns the auth token.  This gets rid of the need for storing the client id and secret in the app code.

Here are what I've come up with:

1) Require the user to enter their password to access data each time they startup the App.  This is definitely the most foolproof method.  If this were done, I'd probably want to save the userID for convenience, but in that case couldn't use the CAS login (since it's web-based). I might be able to use a headless browser on the backend to log the user into CAS and retrieve the token based on what they enter in the Android form, but this seems hacky. Saving the userID is similar to what the Chase app does (if you happen to use this one) - it saves the userID but not your password between sessions.

2) Store the auth token on the Android device. This is a little less secure, but almost foolproof. When the user starts the app for the first time, open the webpage to the CAS login of the proxy server that returns the token (similar to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps).  After the user logs in and the token is returned to the app, encrypt it and store it private to the application.  Also, use ProGuard to obfuscate the code, making the encryption algorithm more difficult to reverse engineer.  I could also work in a token refresh, but I think this would be more of a false sense of security.

3) Don't use CAS but come up with another way to get an auth token for the service.

Any advice of how others have implemented similar scenarios (if it's been done)?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow and answer your question as it is covering a quite broad scope but also goes into detail on different aspects. I'll try a shot in a minute though ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the reason why standards like OAuth are developed is that not everyone has to rethink the same attack vectors again and again. So most often it is your best choice to stick to something already available instead of baking your own thing.

The first problem with clients that are not capable of secretly storing data is that the user's data could be accessed by some attacker. As it is technically not possible to prevent this (code obfuscation won't help you against an expert attacker), the *access token* in OAuth 2 [typically expires](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7030694/1467115) after short time and doesn't give an attacker full access (bounded by *scope*). Certainly you shouldn't store any *refresh token* on such a device.

The second problem is [client impersonation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-10.2). An attacker could steal your *client secret* and access your API in his own (maybe malicious) app. The user would still have to login there himself. The OAuth draft there requires the server to do everything it can to prevent this, but it is really hard.

> The authorization server MUST authenticate the client whenever possible. If the authorization server cannot authenticate the client due to the client's nature, the authorization server MUST require the registration of any redirection URI used for receiving authorization responses, and SHOULD utilize other means to protect resource owners from such potentially malicious clients. For example, the authorization server can engage the resource owner to assist in identifying the client and its origin.

I think Google are the first to try another approach to authenticate a client on such devices, by checking the signature of the application, but they are not yet ready for prime time. If you want more insight into that approach, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11513309/1467115).

For now, your best bet is to stay on the OAuth way, i.e. having the *access token*, *client ID* and *client secrect* (when using the *authorization code grant flow*) on the device, and configure your server to do additional checks. If you feel more secure obfuscating these, just do it, but always think of it as if these values were publicly available.