# Why and when I should update a FCM token?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When the user subscribes for **Web** Push Notifications I get the subscription data that contains an endpoint and keys (auth & p256dh).

Then, I can send the subscription data to the [Instance ID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_registration_tokens_for_push_subscriptions) and get a FCM Token ID. This way I can send notifications by groups and without worrying about encryption.

But I've noticed that there is an API to refresh the token ID. So, Why and when I should refresh that FCM token?

Comment: i think general answer applies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030694/why-do-access-tokens-expire

Comment: @OlegBogdanov No. This is not related to OAuth. It's about Firebase Cloud Messaging **Token ID** or **Registration ID** used to send notifications to a specific device/browser/app.

Comment: I know, it was a reference to 'why should one refresh any token...'

Comment: @OlegBogdanov Ok, thank you. I think FCM refreshes a token every X time. So, I suppose this API just allows to make it sooner if needed.