# Why do OAuth2 access token use expires_in instead of expiring time?

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, access-token

I understood why Access Tokens have to be expired ([here is the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030694/why-do-access-tokens-expire)), but I am a bit confused about the purpose of the expires_in:

1. `expires_in` seems to be less useful than a fixed time, since there are delay in network operations and extra computation as well. Why don't we simply use a standard time (like Unix timestamp or ISO 8601)?
2. As in that topic, if we are assuming Access Tokens are very short-lived, are we going to "bomb" the OAuth2 server with refresh token for every operation?